# Upsert many documents based on _id

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to **upsert** many documents based on **_id**.


E.g.

document_1 = `{_id:"1", "age":11, "name":"name1"}`

document_2 = `{_id:"2", "age":22, "name":"name2"}`


I wrote the below

```
db.my_collection.updateMany(
    { _id: {"$in":["1","2"] } },
    [
        {$set: {_id:"1", "age":11, "name":"name1"}},
        {$set: {_id:"2", "age":22, "name":"name2"}}
    ],
    true
    )
```

But no rows gets updated or inserted. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `true` in the 3rd parameter, you have to pass `{new: true, upsert: true}`.

Comment: Get error ```unrecognized update options field: new```

Comment: remove `new: true`. only pass `upsert: true` as 3rd parameter

Comment: Changed 3rd parameter to ```{upsert: true}``` . Only inserts OR updates document _id = 2. document _id = 1 is neither inserted nor updated. Please help

Comment: Kindly go through this [link](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/)

Comment: Sorry, I went through the link, but couldn't make the query work.

Comment: I guess you have to pass `{multi:true, upsert: true}`.

Answer (score 0):

`$merge` seems to be a better option for upsert operation. You can store the records you want to upsert in another collection, says `to_be_inserted` and perform `$merge` in the aggregation pipeline.

```js
db.to_be_upserted.aggregate([
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "my_collection",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "merge",
      "whenNotMatched": "insert"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rljnWbDvyUC) for your reference.